# Conditional styling of PrimeNG TreeNodes using templates

Tags: css, angular, primeng, tree-nodes

I am well aware of how you can style all your nodes at the same time but I need to add one styling if the node is a leaf (the node has children) but no parent and if the node has a parent but no children.
Here is my code.

```
<p-tree [value]="nodes" layout="horizontal">
        <ng-template let-node pTemplate="default">
                <p>ADD CONTENT HERE</p>
        </ng-template>
    </p-tree>
```

Inspecting the styles once rendered shows that the class I need to change for each of the two conditions is `ui-treenode`

[image]

Adding classes to the `styleClass` attribute of `p-tree` makes it possible to style every node but I am not able to set anything conditionally here.
Adding the conditional style within the template does not function as I want since the `pTemplate` renders the styles that I need to change.

I have read PrimeNG documentation several times and I haven't found any solution to this.
Is there something build in or maybe a viable work around?

**EDIT**
Riscie suggested a solution but the class added in his demo is way deeper than the one I need to change. The class `ui-treenode` is located at the top of the console window where the custom class `leaf-style` is way deeper located in the bottom of the console window.

[image]

So why do I need to change that specific style? Because it adds some padding to the node - which I want to remove in certain cases and not all cases.

**SECOND EDIT**

This might not be the best way and I am not sure of its browser compatibility but it works as intended.

First of, add id to first div inside the template: `id="{{node.data.id}}"`
Second, loop through all nodes in ngAfterViewInit, fetch the node by id and its closest parent with the class `ui-treenode` and the add the classes according to the conditions:

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
 jQuery('.ui-tree-toggler').addClass('d-none');
 jQuery('.ui-treenode-content').addClass('shadow');
 jQuery('.ui-treenode-content').addClass('fp-tree-node');

 this.nodes.forEach(node => {
    this.setClasses(node);
 });
}

setClasses(node: TreeNode) {
 if(!node.children || node.children.length === 0) {
   let thisNode = jQuery(`#${node.data.id}`);
   let styleParent = thisNode.closest(".ui-treenode")
   styleParent[0].classList.add("pl-0");
 }

 if(!node.data.parentId) {
  let thisNode = jQuery(`#${node.data.id}`);
  let styleParent = thisNode.closest(".ui-treenode")
  styleParent[0].classList.add("pr-0");
 }

 if (node.children && node.children.length > 0) {
    node.children.forEach(child => {
      this.setClasses(child);
    });
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<p-tree [value]="nodes" layout="horizontal">
    <ng-template let-node pTemplate="default">
        <p 
            [class.leaf-style]="node.leaf" 
            [class.no-leaf-style]="!node.leaf"
        >
             ADD CONTENT HERE
        </p>
    </ng-template>
</p-tree>
```

Then use the `.leaf-style` and `.no-leaf-style` classes in your stylesheet.

**Update:**

It should work:
See: https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-xzmmf9

Comment: Thanks for your reply but as mentioned - adding styles inside the template does not change the styles needed. The style I need to change is `ui-treenode` which is rendered within the `pTemplate="default"` template..

Comment: I think it does. See my updated answer with the stackblitz example. Maybe I'm not understanding correctly?

Comment: I might not be clear in my question though but if you inspect your demo you can see that your custom style is way deeper than the style that I need to change.
I have edited my question with a screenshot.